# @helper directive no longer works out of the box in ASP.NET5 MVC6 beta4.

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Since I updated my ASP.NET5 project to **beta4** (the one included with Visual Studio 2015 RC), any of my Razor views where I use a helper, such as:

```
@helper foo()
{
   <h2>Bar</h2>
}
```

results in the following error:

*error CS0103: The name 'helper' does not exist in the current context.*

Is the `@helper` directive no longer supported? Can someone point me to anything useful about the issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `@helper` directive was removed since beta 4 because it imposed too many restrictions on other Razor features: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/281.

**Edit**
To be clear: based on the discussion in the GitHub issue(s) Microsoft is not planning to bring the `@helper` directive back or replace it in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: View helpers were a bad idea from day 1, anyways.

Comment: This is my most hated type of SO answer: it answers the question while being entirely useless with regard to providing any alternative or guidance on the correct way to solve the same problem. What replaces the helper, or rather, what should be used in it's stead?

Comment: @JonStory I get your point. However - in the issue I point to, even Microsoft did not come up with any replacement for this feature. Unfortunately there aren't any replacements and it's considered an obsolete feature. I wonder why such a rant comment is necessary when reading the issue clarifies what I just said.

Comment: That's rather the point, though - I didn't know whether Microsoft had made a replacement, so including that in the answer would have been good

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using a helper method, you can achieve the same functionality using a partial with a view model.  Just pass the relevant arguments into the Html.Partial command.

Comment: See Eilon's answer here for an example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606985/recursion-in-asp-net-core-razor-views

Comment: If you're on .NET Core 3+ a local `void` method that calls itself would eliminate the need to create a new partial.

Answer (score 3):

In .Net Core and above you can use the [function derivative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#functions) to achieve the same purpose:

```
@functions {
    private void RenderFoo()
    {
        <h2>Bar</h2>
    }
}

<div>@{ RenderFoo(); }</div>
```

Comment: So that builds strings instead of giving you Razor-type html-code mixing like helpers did?

Comment: Ahh, sorry that's confusing. No, function derivatives work the same as @helper in that they can render any razor template. I'll improve my example to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[Templated Razor Delegates](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/) will be a good alternative.

Declare `foo`

```cs
@{
    Func<dynamic, object> foo =
    @<h2>Bar</h2>
    ;
}
```

Render `foo`

```cs
@foo(null)
```

---

As an advanced example, this can be turned into localization helper.

For example case, localization of text having HTML tags like this.

`Please <a href="~/logout">Logout</a> once`

Rewrite like the following code:

page.cshtml

```html
@inject SubstitutableHtmlUsecase SubstitutableHtmlUsecase
@inject IStringLocalizer<Msg> Msg


@SubstitutableHtmlUsecase.Render1(
    Msg["Please {logout} once"],
    "{logout}", @<a href="~/logout">@Msg["Logout"]</a>)
```

SubstitutableHtmlUsecase.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace App.Usecases
{
    public class SubstitutableHtmlUsecase
    {
        public IHtmlContent Render1(string body, string marker1, Func<object?, IHtmlContent> razor1)
        {
            var parts = body.Split(marker1);

            return new Renderer(
                (writer, encoder) =>
                {
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < parts.Length; idx++)
                    {
                        bool isLast = (idx + 1 == parts.Length);
                        encoder.Encode(writer, parts[idx]);
                        if (!isLast)
                        {
                            razor1(null).WriteTo(writer, encoder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        private class Renderer : IHtmlContent
        {
            private readonly Action<TextWriter, HtmlEncoder> _writer;

            public Renderer(Action<TextWriter, HtmlEncoder> writer)
            {
                _writer = writer;
            }

            public void WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
            {
                _writer(writer, encoder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```