# Where is @helper directive in Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'am testing MVC 5 a bit and it seems that @helper directive in Razor views is not supported any more.

Has it been renamed or replaced with something new?

Comment: possible duplicate of [@helper directive no longer works out of the box in ASP.NET5 MVC6 beta4.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970447/helper-directive-no-longer-works-out-of-the-box-in-asp-net5-mvc6-beta4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reference to your view: @using System.Web.Helpers;

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. cannot reference it. Does not exist. Maybe it is also related to new version of Asp.Net.   I have other helpers available. Like "scripts" and "inject". So I guess "helper" is not there anymore.

Comment: Updated answer. Try to add reference for library.